# Python Selenium - Issue with clicking button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am brand new to Selenium and am attempting to scrape some reviews off a realtor profile on zillow.com. I am running into an issue when attempting to simulate a click on a button element that switches the review page. I am expecting to be able to select a button by xpath and simulate a click on that button, which should move to the next review page. I believe I have selected the button correctly, but the program is failing when I click it.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.zillow.com/profile/AGENTPROFILE"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)

# There are two buttons with the title "Next page", I am grabbing the second one
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Next page']")
next_review_button = buttons[-1]

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# Issue occurs here
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(next_review_button)).click()
```

Running this program in the terminal is successful. A Firefox window is opened and it navigates to the correct url. Furthermore, the browser navigates to the bottom of the page where the button is located, which makes me feel more confident that the button was selected properly. The issue is I get a red error box in the bottom right of my screen with the message "Something went wrong, please try again later".

The message is incredibly vague, so I took a look at the console in my browser after running the code and saw this warning message:

'Cookie “AWSALB” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read [https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite'](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite%27)

My hunch is that this has something to do with what is going wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it. After doing some reading I tried adding the following line of code, which did not do the trick:

```
driver.add_cookie({"name": "AWSALB", "value": "None", "sameSite": "None"})
```

At this point I am not sure what to try next, and was hoping somebody a bit more experienced than me could point me in the right direction. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: That error seems to be not related to the problem. Try to sleep enough time, such as 3 sec after it finished to wait the button to be clickable. A button being clickable does not mean the site is ready to process the 'next page' request.

Comment: It is not because of your code, the website is blocking the access through automated code.

Comment: @relent95 I will try your suggestion when I have a moment today. Thank you both for your responses.